# How do I get this program to replace the items next to the rightmost H

Tags: python

This program is supposed to get a user input of something along the lines of: HTTHHTH
then remove the right most H and flip its neighbors so that the line HTTHHTT would look like HTTTHT and it would keep doing this until there is either one H left or until there is no H's. Something like TTTT, would end the code and print Not successful, while something like HHHH would go

```
HHHH
HHT
TH
H
Success!
```

This is my program:

```
# finds if a user inputted pattern of H's and T's will go through an algorithm and come out with 1 H or no H's

# loop to allow user to retry if an invalid input was detected
while True: 
  # asks user for input
  startstring = input("Please enter a string made of only H's and T's: ").upper()
  # sets of characters for later
  allowed1 = set('H' + 'T')
  allowed2 = set('H')

  # checks if all the characters in the user inputed string are of set 1
  if set(startstring) <= allowed1:
    # turns the string into a list
    stringlist = [i for i in startstring]
    # prints the unaffected list
    print(*stringlist)
    # loops allows for the algorithm to run through each index
    for i in range(len(stringlist),0,-1):
      # checks if the last character is H
      if stringlist[i-1] == 'H':
        # checks if there is a character to the left of the rightmost H
        try:
          if stringlist[i-2] == 'H':
            stringlist[i-2] = 'T'
          elif stringlist[i-2] == 'T':
            stringlist[i-1] = 'H'
        except:
          continue
        # checks if there is a character to the right of the rightmost H
        try:
          if stringlist[i-1] == 'H':
            stringlist[i-2] = 'T'
          elif stringlist[-1] == 'T':
            stringlist[i-1] = 'H'
        except:
          continue
        # removes the right most H
        stringlist.pop(i-1)
        # prints the new line
        print(*stringlist)
      # skips the character if it is not H
      elif stringlist[i-1] != 'H':
        continue
    
    break
  # error statement
  elif set(startstring) != allowed1:
    print("Invalid input, please try again.\n")

# creates empty string for later
startstring = ""
# converts list to string
for i in range(0,len(stringlist)):
  startstring += stringlist[i]

# checks if the string has only one H
if set(startstring) <= allowed2:
  print("success!")
# checks if the string has no H's
else:
  print("Not successful")
```

However my code when using the input HTTHHTH prints:

```
H T T H H T H
H T T H H H
H T T H T
H T H T
H H T
T T
Not successful
```

When it should print:

```
H T T H H T H
H T T H H H
H T T H T
H T H H
H T T
H T
H
success!
```

What is the problem with my code?

Comment: I run your code but give me a different output:`H T T H H T H`,`H T T H H T`,`H T T T T`,`T T T T`,`Not successful`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're a bit overcomplicating the whole thing - try with recursion:

```py
def foo(txt):
    if txt.count("H") < 2:
        return "Success" if txt.count("H")==1 else "Failure"
    id_H = len(txt)-txt[::-1].index("H")-1
    if id_H > 0:
        txt[id_H-1] = "H" if txt[id_H-1]=="T" else "T"
    if len(txt) - 1 > id_H:
        txt[id_H+1] = "H" if txt[id_H+1]=="T" else "T"
    return foo(txt[:id_H]+txt[id_H+1:])
```

Sample run:

```py
sample = [
    "H T T H H T H".split(" "),
    "H H H H".split(" "),
    "H T T H H T".split(" "),
    "H T T T T".split(" "),
    "T T T T".split(" "),
]

for el in sample:
    print(el)
    print(foo(el))
```

Outputs:

```py
['H', 'T', 'T', 'H', 'H', 'T', 'H']
Success
['H', 'H', 'H', 'H']
Success
['H', 'T', 'T', 'H', 'H', 'T']
Failure
['H', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T']
Success
['T', 'T', 'T', 'T']
Failure
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of bug/unstandard coding style in your code, here's the few explanation and suggestion:

1. The number in `try-expect` block went wrong, it should be `i-2` and `i`.You maybe do a lot typo here, such as `i-1`,`-1`.
2. The continue in `try-expect` will stop the loop if `i-1` is the most left.You should use `if` to check it.
3. You need write the code with clear logic, such as use `i` instead of `i-1`.
4. Using too many `continue` makes the logic really confusing. You actually only run the `for` loop once.
5. The input of `startstring` should outside of `while` loop, rather then inside `while` loop.
6. The `# skips the character if it is not H` part actually did nothing, should remove it.
7. You should check the `error statements` first, rather than check it in `loop`.
8. No need to clear the `startstring` in python, you can use `function`.
9. Please try to give `4-spaces indentation` to write python code. It is bit more standard.
10. Don't use `{variable}+{number}` like `allowed1` `allowed2`.They are really confusing.

## The code fixed from your code:

```
def bar(startstring):
    if not all(c in 'HT' for c in startstring) or startstring == "":
        print("Invalid input, please try again.\n")
    else:
        while True: 
            print(*[i for i in startstring])
            allowed1 = set('H' + 'T')
            if set(startstring) <= allowed1:
                stringlist = [i for i in startstring]
                for i in range(len(stringlist)-1,-1,-1):
                    if stringlist[i] == 'H':
                        if i-1>=0:
                            if stringlist[i-1] == 'H':
                                stringlist[i-1] = 'T'
                            elif stringlist[i-1] == 'T':
                                stringlist[i-1] = 'H'
                        if i+1<len(stringlist):
                            if stringlist[i+1] == 'H':
                                stringlist[i+1] = 'T'
                            elif stringlist[i+1] == 'T':
                                stringlist[i+1] = 'H'
                        stringlist.pop(i)
                        startstring = "".join(stringlist)
                        break
            if startstring == "H":
                print(*[i for i in startstring])
                print("success!")
                break
            elif not "H" in startstring:
                print(*[i for i in startstring])
                print("Not successful")
                break
bar("HTTHHTH")
bar("TTTT")
bar("HHHH")
bar("")
```

### Result:

```
H T T H H T H
H T T H H H
H T T H T
H T H H
H T T
H T
H
success!
T T T T
T T T T
Not successful
H H H H
H H T
T H
H
success!
Invalid input, please try again.
```

## My suggestion/code:

```
def foo(s):
    if not all(c in 'HT' for c in s) or s == "":
        print("Invalid input, please try again.\n")
        return
    while "H" in s and s != "H":
        sub_s = [i for i in s]
        print(*sub_s)
        i = len(sub_s)-1
        while sub_s[i]!= "H":
            i-=1
        if i-1>=0:
            sub_s[i-1] = "H" if sub_s[i-1] == "T" else "T"
        if i+1<len(s):
            sub_s[i+1] = "H" if sub_s[i+1] == "T" else "T"
        sub_s.pop(i)
        s = "".join(sub_s)
    sub_s = [i for i in s]
    print(*sub_s)
    if s == "H":
        print("success!")
    elif not "H" in s:
        print("Not successful")
        
foo("HTTHHTH")
foo("TTTT")
foo("HHHH")
foo("")
```

### Result:

```
H T T H H T H
H T T H H H
H T T H T
H T H H
H T T
H T
H
success!
T T T T
Not successful
H H H H
H H T
T H
H
success!
Invalid input, please try again.
```